# Numpy split array where NaN ends

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array as follows:

```
x =
[[ 839.41    128.3      92.47     51.78         nan]
 [ 823.      126.43     91.31     51.63         nan]
 [ 819.      126.6      93.03     51.77         nan]
 [ 776.32    123.6      93.85     52.02         nan]
 [ 755.12    120.93     92.48     49.955        nan]
 [ 739.01    129.84     97.68     50.75         nan]
 [ 760.17    128.36     98.26     51.1          nan]
 [ 780.37    131.57     98.82     51.52         nan]
 [ 740.34    129.89     98.5      50.48         nan]
 [ 768.65    133.37    104.86     51.71         nan]
 [ 757.75    135.15    103.93     50.9297       nan]
 [ 760.58    135.02    105.15     51.91         nan]
 [ 750.03    134.15    104.28     50.84         nan]
 [ 795.99    133.56    109.02     53.92     57.12  ]
 [ 817.13    135.      108.04     52.92     57.84  ]
 [ 808.23    135.6     107.645    53.2      57.66  ]]
```

What would be the best possible way to split the array where the nan ends i.e.

```
x =
[[ 839.41    128.3      92.47     51.78         nan]
 [ 823.      126.43     91.31     51.63         nan]
 [ 819.      126.6      93.03     51.77         nan]
 [ 776.32    123.6      93.85     52.02         nan]
 [ 755.12    120.93     92.48     49.955        nan]
 [ 739.01    129.84     97.68     50.75         nan]
 [ 760.17    128.36     98.26     51.1          nan]
 [ 780.37    131.57     98.82     51.52         nan]
 [ 740.34    129.89     98.5      50.48         nan]
 [ 768.65    133.37    104.86     51.71         nan]
 [ 757.75    135.15    103.93     50.9297       nan]
 [ 760.58    135.02    105.15     51.91         nan]
 [ 750.03    134.15    104.28     50.84         nan]]
[[ 795.99    133.56    109.02     53.92     57.12  ]
 [ 817.13    135.      108.04     52.92     57.84  ]]
```

And if I call `x[0]` it would result in the subarray with `nans` in it, and if I called `x[1]` it would result in the subarray below that.

**Note**

I would like the array to split at the end of every series of nans, the example I gave above just conveniently had all the `nans` in lined up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that `nan`s are continues in a column you can find the latest index of that respective row as following:

```
In [16]: np.where(np.isnan(x).any(1))[0][-1] + 1
Out[16]: 13
```

Then you can split the array using `np.split()`:

```
np.split(x, [np.where(np.isnan(x).any(1))[0][-1] + 1])
```

If you are not sure of that, i.e. the `nan`s can exist in any index. You can perform a similar approach on the raveled version of your array and find the index by dividing the latest `nan` to the second axis length.

```
In [38]: (np.where(np.isnan(x.ravel()))[0][-1] + 1)//x.shape[1]
Out[38]: 13
```

Demo:

```
In [18]: np.split(x, [np.where(~np.isnan(x).any(1))[0][0]])
Out[18]: 
[array([[839.41  , 128.3   ,  92.47  ,  51.78  ,      nan],
        [823.    , 126.43  ,  91.31  ,  51.63  ,      nan],
        [819.    , 126.6   ,  93.03  ,  51.77  ,      nan],
        [776.32  , 123.6   ,  93.85  ,  52.02  ,      nan],
        [755.12  , 120.93  ,  92.48  ,  49.955 ,      nan],
        [739.01  , 129.84  ,  97.68  ,  50.75  ,      nan],
        [760.17  , 128.36  ,  98.26  ,  51.1   ,      nan],
        [780.37  , 131.57  ,  98.82  ,  51.52  ,      nan],
        [740.34  , 129.89  ,  98.5   ,  50.48  ,      nan],
        [768.65  , 133.37  , 104.86  ,  51.71  ,      nan],
        [757.75  , 135.15  , 103.93  ,  50.9297,      nan],
        [760.58  , 135.02  , 105.15  ,  51.91  ,      nan],
        [750.03  , 134.15  , 104.28  ,  50.84  ,      nan]]),
 array([[795.99 , 133.56 , 109.02 ,  53.92 ,  57.12 ],
        [817.13 , 135.   , 108.04 ,  52.92 ,  57.84 ],
        [808.23 , 135.6  , 107.645,  53.2  ,  57.66 ]])]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
wh = np.isnan(x).any(1).argmin()
```

Then `x[:wh]` and `x[wh:]` are what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If all `nan` are in the last column, you can use

```
x = [x[np.where(np.isnan(x[:, 4])), :][0], x[np.where(~np.isnan(x[:, 4])), :][0]]
```

I kept your notation of reusing the variable `x`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the Q correctly, more than two blocks are possible---and none of the answers posted so far seem to address this.

The following code splits whenever a column of `nan`s ends:

```
>>> A = np.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 4)).astype(float)
>>> for i in range(4):
...     A[slice(*np.sort(np.random.randint(2*i, 2*i + 6, (2,)))), np.random.randint(0, 4)] = np.nan
... 
>>> A
array([[ 3.,  9.,  1.,  7.],
       [ 1.,  8.,  3.,  0.],
       [nan,  1.,  7.,  9.],
       [nan,  1.,  9.,  0.],
       [nan,  3.,  8.,  6.],
       [ 3.,  2.,  6.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  7.,  9.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  6.,  7., nan],
       [ 3.,  0.,  9., nan],
       [nan,  2.,  2.,  2.]])
>>> 
>>> nans = np.isnan(A)
>>> idx  = np.where((nans[:-1] & ~nans[1:]).any(axis=1))[0] + 1
>>> 
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> 
>>> pprint(np.split(A, idx, axis=0))
[array([[ 3.,  9.,  1.,  7.],
       [ 1.,  8.,  3.,  0.],
       [nan,  1.,  7.,  9.],
       [nan,  1.,  9.,  0.],
       [nan,  3.,  8.,  6.]]),
 array([[ 3.,  2.,  6.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  7.,  9.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  6.,  7., nan],
       [ 3.,  0.,  9., nan]]),
 array([[nan,  2.,  2.,  2.]])]
```